# Hide custom meta field based on cart weight

Tags: woocommerce, custom-fields, woocommerce-checkout-fields

For a WooCommerce shop, based on a Shipping Zone I have three custom fieldgroups showing at checkout. I want to hide two of those fieldgroups depending on the total weight of the Cart.

By default the checkout shows all three fieldgroups because they are tied to the same shipping zone.

Three weight categories:
upto 500kg (Should just show this fieldgroup meta name)
_review_order_before_payment_blue_zone_500)

501-1000kg (Should just show this fieldgroup meta name) _review_order_before_payment_collection_blue_zone_500_1000

1001+kg  (Should just show this fieldgroup meta name)
_review_order_before_payment_collection_blue_zone_1001

This is the code I've cobbled together, but its not hiding the fieldgroup. Any ideas?

```
// Unset checkout field based on cart weight
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'remove_custom_checkout_field', 999 );
function remove_custom_checkout_field( $fields ) {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() >= 500 ) {
        unset($fields['_review_order_before_payment_collection_blue_zone_500_1000']); // Unset field
    }
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() >= 1001 ) {
        unset($fields['_review_order_before_payment_collection_blue_zone_1001']); // Unset field
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Expected fieldgroups to disappear when weight was calculated.

Comment: this is part of billing fields order fields address fields ? Also check value in WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() - For example if its 0.500kg will return 0.5 if your weight is set to kg.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The fields I'm trying to unset are hooked into 'Before Payment' (woocommerce_review_order_before_payment). So I presume I'm looking to access 'order'?. I've tried adding ['order'] but its still not unsetting from Checkout. 
(For testing, your code works on the site as expected)

Comment: Share the code how you set your fields to understand where is the problem. My answer below works so i guess you are not pointing to the field. What you can do is to debug $fields .

Comment: ```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'remove_custom_checkout_field', 999 );
function remove_custom_checkout_field( $fields ) {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() <= 500 ) {
        unset($fields['order']['_review_order_before_payment_collection_blue_zone_500_1000']); // Unset field
    }
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() <= 1001 ) {
        unset($fields['order']['_review_order_before_payment_collection_blue_zone_1001']); // Unset field
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: This is the same code in your question. I am asking how you **set** the fields

Comment: Apologies. The fields have been created using a third party plugin (flexible-checkout-fields-pro). 
It creates a 'name' off of the entered Label: collection_blue_zone_501_1000
and a unique 'meta' field (incl. in the above code): _review_order_before_payment_collection_blue_zone_500_1000
Note: I've tried entering both possibilities, but still no dice.
Video showing setup (in 'Before Payment' checkout section): https://cln.sh/RRcgmc3p

Comment: easiest way is to debug $fields and see what is returning.

Comment: So the plugin authors have informed me that the 'meta' name (_review_order_before_payment_collection_blue_zone_500_1000) is the field I'm targeting. So there must be something else wrong with the code? I've tried swapping out ['order'] for ['checkout'] and even ['billing'] but I still can't unset the thing (I've checked the weight values).

Comment: debug.. is your solution nothing else. i dont have cristal ball to guess. Since you are in contact with the plugin author he can point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should declare field based on if its billing, shipping, order etc. Read more about here - https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

In my case my weight is set to kg and testing product is 0.5kg. You can add your condition in `custom_woocommerce_billing_fields` and skip `remove_checkout_fields_by_weight` function.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');
function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{
    $fields['billing_test'] = array(
        'label' => __('Test field', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), 
        'required' => false, 
        'clear' => false, 
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array('my-css')
    );
    return $fields;
}

function remove_checkout_fields_by_weight( $fields ) {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight() >= 0.5 ) {
        unset( $fields['billing']['billing_test'] );
    }
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'remove_checkout_fields_by_weight' );
```